# Sorting users using date from separate collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to get return a list of users based on their `accountActiveDate` which is stored in a separate collection. If I console.log candidateUserIDByDate it returns the users in the correct order however when I return Meteor.users.find using the var candidateUserIDByDate its not sorted.

Path: `sort.js`

```
let sortCandidatesByDate = CandidateAccountStatus.find({}, {sort: {accountActiveDate: 1}}).fetch();
let candidateUserIDByDate = _.map(sortCandidatesByDate, function(obj) {
  return obj.candidateUserId;
});

return Meteor.users.find({$and: [{_id: { $ne: Meteor.userId() }}, {_id: { $in: candidateUserIDByDate }}]});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a (probably hackish) solution would be, returning the `CandidateAccountStatus` and inside the loop, using another helper to return the correct user like this:

Template helpers:

```
status: function(){
    //you might want to do {$ne: {Meteor.userId()}} for the correct field
    //in your selector if you don't want currentUser status
    return CandidateAccountStatus.find({}, {sort: {accountActiveDate: 1}})
},

statusUser: function(){
    //change correctField to how you save the userId to
    //your CandidateAccountStatus schema
    return Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.correctField})
}
```

HTML

```
{{#each status}}
    {{#with statusUser}}
        <!-- You have the user object here -->
        {{_id}} <!-- gives the userId -->
    {{/with}}
{{/each}}
```